# align text to the bottom of column (without using table-cell)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to align a div/text to the bottom of a column with no success. I would rather not use table-cell if it can be avoided.

```css
#jBtn {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

#jTxt { 
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="jTxt">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Something Something</h1>
    <h2>sub-Title</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="jBtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to keep `#jBtn` to stay at the `bottom`. Even `position: absolute` doesn't seem the work.

EDIT:

I need the jTxt div to remain at the bottom of its parent so it needs to remain position: absolute

Comment: can you please give some more details? with some more clarity.

Comment: My answer doesn't affect the `jTxt` element's CSS rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `position: relative` on `jBtn`'s parent `<div class="col-md-6">` together with `position: absolute` on `jBtn` it should work.

Here I added a new class, `po-re`, to not mess with the `col-md-6` class.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 po-re">
    <div id="jBtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.po-re {
  position: relative;
}

#jBtn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;    /* adjust to your values */
  height: 20px;   /* adjust to your values */
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
```